# Pixel-wise image manipulation

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, image-processing

I downloaded an image from a website and imported it to Mathematica

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPZM7.jpg"];
Export["/path/to/file/fPZM7.txt", 
 Flatten[MapIndexed[Join[#2, #1] &, ImageData[img], {2}], 1], "Table"]
```

and create a .txt file with the pixel information

```
{{1, 1, 0.219608, 0.215686, 0.196078}, {1, 2, 0.219608, 0.215686,  0.196078}, 
 {1, 3, 0.219608, 0.215686, 0.196078}, {1, 4, 0.219608,   0.215686, 0.196078}, 
 {1, 5, 0.219608, 0.215686, 0.196078}, ..... , 
 {944, 1396, 0.054902, 0.054902, 0.0470588}, {944, 1397, 0.00392157, 0.00784314, 0.}, 
 {944, 1398, 0.00784314, 0.0117647, 0.}, {944, 1399, 0.0470588, 0.0509804, 0.027451}, 
 {944, 1400, 0.0588235, 0.0627451, 0.0313725}}
```

which is a list of positions located at integer numbers followed by three real numbers defining the RGB color information of each point.

Then I import the `.txt` file

```
import = Import["/path/to/file/fPZM7.txt", "Data"]
```

and reconstruct the image using the basic code

```
Show[
  Table[
   Graphics[{
     RGBColor[import[[i, 3]], import[[i, 4]], import[[i, 5]]], 
     Point[{import[[i, 1]], import[[i, 2]]}]
   }],
   {i, 1, Length[import]}
 ]
]
```

So far, the image is reconstructed (after a long long time) with no issues. However, if instead I want to manipulate the positions of the pixels, like

```
Show[Table[Graphics[{RGBColor[import[[i, 3]], import[[i, 4]], import[[i, 5]]], Point[{import[[i, 1]], import[[i, 2]]^2}]}], {i, 1, Length[import]}]]
```

or

```
Show[Table[Graphics[{RGBColor[import[[i, 3]], import[[i, 4]], import[[i, 5]]], Point[{import[[i, 1]], Sin[import[[i, 2]]]}]}], {i, 1, Length[import]}]]
```

I get a graphic in blank.

Does anybody know what happens there?

I would like to be able to manipulate the pixel positions and reconstruct another image out of the original one by changing the position of the pixels. 
Since all this process takes a lot of time: Does anybody know a more efficient way to plot the image back and the transformation?

Comment: You know about `Raster[]`, yes?

Comment: Let's leave aside how you are doing your calculations. What I don't understand is, what result you envision. You are modifying the *positions* of the pixels, e.g. by squaring one coordinate. This introduces gaps in the coordinates, i.e. instead of going `{1,1},{1,2},{1,3}`, they will give `{1,1},{1,4},{1,9}`. When you reconstruct your image, what values should we assign to the missing pixels in the new image, e.g. the ones between 1,4 and {1,9}?

Comment: If you want to move the pixels around, look at ImageTransformation and ImageForwardTransformation. If you want to change the values of the pixels themselves, ImageFilter and related commands would be your friend.

Comment: wow, thanks so much, ImageForwardTransformation solved my problem.